# Send request to elastic watcher via curl

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

ELK 7.X

I am trying to create elastic search watcher with curl using the input file. Something like this

```
curl -X PUT _watcher/watch/cluster_health_watch --data-binary @inputFile
```

1) What is the file type to be used ? Most of the data is json, but in "actions" field when sending an email, the email body can be HTML !

2) Is there any way that the HTML in the body can be referred from an external file, such that input file can be json ?

Comment: What's the response you get?

Comment: I'm not able to pass the file as json, since it contains html body in email section

Comment: I mean the exact error message you receive from elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escaped the double quotes in the html string by adding "\".

Ex:-

```
<h3 style=\"color:red\"></h3>
```

```
"actions": {
    "send_email": {
      "email": {
        "to": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "subject": "My Subject",
        "body": {
          "html": "<h3 style=\"color:red\"> There was a problem</h3>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
curl -X PUT _watcher/watch/cluster_health_watch -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary @inputFile.json
```